# Selecting row data and a scaler in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a job table, where each job has some metrics like cost, time taken, etc. I'd like to select information for a set of jobs, like the requestor and job action, and in addition to that row data, select some high-level metrics (min cost, max cost, min time taken, etc.).

The data changes frequently, so I'd like to get this information in a single select. Is it possible to do this? I'm not sure if this is conceptually possible because the DB would have to return row-level data along with aggregate data.

Right now I can get all the details and calculate the min/max, something like this:

```
select requestor, action, cost, time_taken from job;
```

But then I have to write code to find the min/max and this query has to download all the cost/time data when I am really only interested in the min/max. I really want to do something like

```
select (min(cost), max(cost), min(time_taken), max(time_taken)), (requestor, action) from job;
```

And get the aggregate data first, and then the row level data. Is this possible? (On a real server this is on MySQL, but for dev I locally use sqlite so it'd be nice if it worked there too, but not required).

The table looks something like this:

```
+----+-----------+--------+------+------------+
| id | requestor | action | cost | time_taken |
+----+-----------+--------+------+------------+
| 1  |     31233 | sync   |    8 |      423.3 |
+----+-----------+--------+------+------------+
| 2  |     11229 | read   |    1 |        1.3 |
+----+-----------+--------+------+------------+
| 3  |      1434 | edit   |    5 |      152.8 |
+----+-----------+--------+------+------------+
| 4  |    101781 | sync   |   12 |      712.1 |
+----+-----------+--------+------+------------+
```

I'd like to get back the stats:

min/max cost: `1`/`12`

min/max time_taken: `1.3`/`712.1`

and all the requestors and actions:

```
+-----------+--------+
| requestor | action |
+-----------+--------+
|     31233 | sync   |
+-----------+--------+
|     11229 | read   |
+-----------+--------+
|      1434 | edit   |
+-----------+--------+
|    101781 | sync   |
+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select requestor, action, min(cost), max(cost), min(time_taken), max(time_taken),
from job
group by requestor, action;
```

Comment: I believe doing the `min()` and `max()` with the `group by` gets aggregation for each group. I'd like to get an aggregation for the entire select. I have to run a single select since the data frequently, and I'd rather do it in the DB so that I don't have to download all the data since I just need the aggregate info.

Comment: @CharlesL. . . . But you also want the requestor/actions.  What you want might require two queries.